# How to set value according to child value in combobox using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I do not know how to formulate this question but I am writing a ordering shoe system where an employee makes an order for a client and ship that order. Each shoe size has its unique stock and it should be shown in the html view. I am using ASP.NET MVC.
My issue is that... when I load a combobox value ( **$('select#cars').change(function (e)**) the stock sets value but I have many stocks with same class and they set equally. I think I should be using parent and child stuff in JS.

Each product has comobox with unique shoes sizes, but my client wants it to show each shoe size below each comobox depending what you select.

[image]

Values below each combobox should change according what it loads. I am using ajax.
[image]

This is my code:

```
 ...table...
                <td>
                <div>
                    <select name="cars" id="cars" class="" style="width: 100%">
                        <option value=""> ... </option>

                        @foreach (var talla in item.DetalleTallas)
                        {
                <option value="@talla.Talla.Id"> @talla.Talla.NombreTalla </option>
                         }
                    </select>
                    <span class="existencias-talla">X</span>
                </div>
               
            </td>
       ...table...
```

JS Code:

```
$('select#cars').change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tallavalue = $(this).children("option").filter(":selected");


        var datos = JSON.stringify({
            valuee: tallavalue.val()
        });


        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Inventario/RetornarExistencia/",
            data: datos,
            success: function (result) {

                $(".existencias-talla").html(result);



            },
            error: function () {
                alert("SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR, REVISE SI LA INFORMACIÓN ESTA COMPLETA Y CORRECTA");
            }
        });

    });
```

In JS code in ***(result)*** returns the unique stock for each shoe size but others shoes sizes changes at same time. How do I solve this?

PD: I want the code inside success since it loads the stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the instance that is inside the same row BUT you can't repeat ID's in a page so change to using classes on the `<select>`

```
$('select.className').change(function (e) {
    var $select = $(this),
        $span = $select.next()// or $select.parent().find('.existencias-talla')

    $.ajax({
       ...
        success: function (result) {

            $span.html(result);

        }
        ...
```

Comment: I thought that I was obligated to use .children() and .parent() stuff to achieve this. Your approaching worked.

Comment: Also can use `$select.val()` instead of looking for the selected option value.

Comment: Why did you use $select instead of var select? never seen such $ in JS.

Comment: I forgot the var ,,,fixed. As for the `$`variable prefix it is a convention that many people use to know that the variable is a jQuery object